# Enabling Navigation and SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation, publishing, web-template

I have activated SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure feature provisioned through my web template. But the Navigation (my libraries in QuickLaunch bar) was not visible after publishing feature activation. For showing navigation, I added following feature to my web template:

```
<Feature ID="541F5F57-C847-4e16-B59A-B31E90E6F9EA">
      <!-- Per-Web Portal Navigation Properties-->
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <Property Value="true" Key="InheritGlobalNavigation"/>
        <Property Value="true" Key="InheritCurrentNavigation"/>        
        <Property Value="true" Key="IncludeSubSites"/>
        <Property Value="true" Key="IncludePages"/>
      </Properties>
    </Feature>
```

But, I could not see navigation (Libraries in QuickLaunch bar) in my site collection. Then I go to Site settings -> Navigation and select last option (structural navigation) from current navigation option and click ok. I can see Navigation now. But My question is, how can I do this through xml provision in my web template ?

Answer (score 1):

I have added following code in feature and then add that feature's id to web template which solves my problem

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

            PublishingWeb navPublish = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
            WebNavigationSettings navSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);
            navSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider; // Structural Navigation
            navSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
            navPublish.Navigation.OrderingMethod = OrderingMethod.Automatic;
            navPublish.Navigation.AutomaticSortingMethod = AutomaticSortingMethod.Title;

            navPublish.Update();
            navSettings.Update();
            web.Update();

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this post - I was struggling with this just recently and didn't think of inserting the code to another feature and activating it from the onet.xml file.